# Wie kann ich "esdrújula" (Proparoxytonon) anders übersetzen?

Tags: translation, synonym

Im Gegensatz zum Deutschen haben wir im Spanischen unheimlich viele auf der drittletzten Silbe betonte Wörter. (Vermutlich) demzufolge haben wir ein einfaches Wort dafür: *esdrújula*.

- Kann ich lediglich [*Proparoxytonon*](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Proparoxytonon) für das Wort *esdrújula* benutzen, ohne überkorrekt zu klingen? Es würde mich nicht überraschen, wenn es kein Wort germanischer, anstelle griechischer, Etymologie gäbe. Trotzdem wünsche ich mir eines.

(Gelegentlich bekomme ich Fragen deutscher Spanisch-Studierenden über das Thema. Das motiviert meine Frage. Ich möchte auch nicht so gerne "auf der vorvorletzten Silbe betonte" gebrauchen.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Wenn Du verstanden werden willst, solltest Du "auf der drittletzten Silbe betontes Wort" sagen. "Proparoxytonon" musste ich nachlesen, und ich denke, die einzigen, die dieses Wort kennen, dürften in der Regel Linguisten sein.

Wenn es im Rahmen des Spanischunterrichts auftritt, würde ich an Deiner Stelle einfach das spanische Wort verwenden (natürlich mit Erklärung bei der ersten Verwendung).